# The process executed with the extension does not find the path to the referenced dll

Tags: dll, process, registry

The process executed with the extension does not find the path to the referenced dll.

It was normally used when it was executed with ".exe".

However, after running with the extension registered in the registry, trying to use the dll results in an error that the dll file cannot be found.

If you look at the content of the exception that occurred, the dll in the path of "C:\myfolder\myDll.dll" try to find to "c:\Windows\system32\myDll.dll".

How do I do anything other than put it in the System folder to ensure that the extension-enabled process recognizes the path in the dll ?

It is not possible to put it in the system folder, so another method is needed.

p.s ) When i open a process by right-clicking an icon in the taskbar while the process is floating, the newly opened process also generates the same invalid dll path error.

Comment: Develop with wpf

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

it cause that "System.Environment.CurrentDirectory" and "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" were different.

so when Application start, Check each directory and change it if it is different.

my case in WPF, System.Environment.CurrentDirectory was Windows System folder.